# Problems to run opencv in antergOS

Tags: python, opencv, archlinux

I have some problems to run opencv in a distro archlinux.

I'm having the following error:

```
Warning: unable to open video source:  0
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 583
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "video.py", line 219, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('capture %d' % i, img)
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:583: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

I am trying to run Python samples as video.py in folder samples of opencv.

I installed this libs using yaourt:

```
core/pkg-config 0.29.2-1 (base-devel) [installed]
    A system for managing library compile/link flags
extra/gtk2 2.24.31-1 [installed]
    GObject-based multi-platform GUI toolkit (legacy)
```

Comment: Did you "Rebuild the library..."?

Comment: yes, I did this.

Comment: I got this same message the other night while running OpenCV on a Docker server. The server had no application to open an image or anything like that; perhaps that's your problem. Try instead writing the image (with `imwrite()` from OpenCV) and then browsing to the location and opening the image with an image viewing application.